# Ionic not working on Safari & iOS 11 Using ServiceStack Client

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, safari, servicestack, ios11

my ionic app not working when calling any webservice (servicestack) method on safari 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.2), see the attched picture
also I have the same problem when run to iOS 11 device or simulator.

the app is working on chrome or any android device.
My MacOS version 10.13.4 (17E199)

[image: servicestack ionic ios safari calling error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this issue was from the [@servicestack/client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@servicestack/client) then it was caused by Safari 11.1 update [that broke W3C's fetch Request API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/610).

A workaround that resolves this issue is available from `@servicestack/client` v1.0.12.